How to connect to Sharepoint on premise site from .NET 8?
Is there any option to connect to an on-premises SharePoint from .NET 8? My SharePoint versions are 2013 and 2016. Most of the Microsoft documentation seems to focus on SharePoint Online.
What is the preferable authentication method for this?

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

public class SharePointADFSExample
{
    private const string SiteUrl = "https://yoursharepoint.onpremises.com/sites/yoursite";
    private const string ADFSUrl = "https://your-adfs-server/adfs/services/trust/mex";
    private const string UserName = "yourusername@domain.com";
    private const string Password = "yourpassword";

    public void ConnectAndOperate()
    {
        using (var ctx = new ClientContext(SiteUrl))
        {
            // SecureString for password
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in Password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            // SharePointOnlineCredentials object for authentication
            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, securePassword);

            // Set credentials and authentication mode
            ctx.Credentials = credentials;
            ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
            ctx.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo(UserName, securePassword);
            ctx.FormsAuthenticationMode = FormsAuthenticationMode.SecurityToken;

            // Set ADFS authentication headers
            ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, e) =>
            {
                e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED"] = "f";
            };

            // Obtain ADFS token
            string fedAuthToken = GetADFSAuthToken(ADFSUrl, UserName, Password);

            // Assign the ADFS token to SharePoint context
            ctx.FedAuth = fedAuthToken;

            // Perform SharePoint operations
            Web web = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(web);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("Connected to SharePoint site: " + web.Title);
        }
    }

    private string GetADFSAuthToken(string adfsUrl, string userName, string password)
    {
        string adfsMetadata = $"{adfsUrl}?wsdl=wsdl0";

        WS2007HttpBinding binding = new WS2007HttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;

        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(adfsMetadata));

        using (WSTrustChannelFactory factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, endpointAddress))
        {
            factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;

            var channel = factory.CreateChannel();

            var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
            {
                RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
                KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
                AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(SiteUrl),
            };

            RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr;
            SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst, out rstr);

            return rstr.RequestedSecurityToken.TokenXml.InnerText;
        }
    }
}


This sharepoint site uses ADFS authentication. In this case, is it possible to setup a service account without using ADFS? I have seen a documentation related to app-only token. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs . I am wondering whether this would be possible in my scenario.
